# Spring managed bean injection in class implementing RowMapper

Tags: java, json, spring, postgresql, inject

I have a class BusinessRowMapper that implements RowMapper to convert PostGres JSONB object to Java object.

```
BusinessRowMapper implements RowMapper<PersonDetails>
```

it overrides mapRow

```
   public class BusinessRowMapper implements RowMapper<PersonDetails> {

    private PersonUtility utils;

    public BusinessRowMapper(PersonUtility utils) {
        super();
        this.utils = utils;
    }


    public PersonDetails mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        PersonDetails personDetail = utils.unMarshallAndConvertData(rs
                .getString(ConstantsV4.COLUMN_CUST_DTLS_JSON_DOC));
        return personDetail;
    }
}
```

Now, How do I do Spring managed Injection of PersonUtility Bean in this BusinessRowMapper bean rather than passing the utility bean as constructor argument to BusinessRowMapper?

```
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(
                        ConstantsV4.RETRIEVE_PERSON_DETAIL_QUERY, params,
                        new BusinessRowMapper(utility));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `PersonUtility` class as spring bean adding `@component` over the class.

Then you can autowire the field in `BusinessRowMapper`

```
@Component 
    public class BusinessRowMapper implements RowMapper<PersonDetails> { 

    @Autowired 
    private PersonUtility utils; 


    ... 


    }
```

Comment: Didn't work. And, How do you invoke this Mapper bean from 
 - getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(
                        ConstantsV4.RETRIEVE_PERSON_DETAIL_QUERY, params,
                        new BusinessRowMapper(utility));